TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL' vite + react In appwrite backend
This is my configuration file to export project id and endPoints.
const EnvConfig = {
  ProjectId: String(import.meta.env.VITE_APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID),
  EndPoint: String(import.meta.env.VITE_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT),
};

export default EnvConfig;


And this is my registration page:
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (name == "" || email == "" || password == "") {
      alert("please enter correct credientials");
    } else {
      register();
      console.log(email);
    }
  };
  const register = async () => {
    try {
      const userAccount = await account.create(
        ID.unique(),
        email,
        password,
        name
      );
      console.log(userAccount);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error from register", error);
    }
  };

i am trying to register a user in a database but it shows type error invalid ulr

my error is in EnvConfig.js
insted of this:
EnvConfig = {
  ProjectId: import.meta.env.VITE_APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID,
  EndPoint:  import.meta.env.VITE_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT,
}

i removed String : In JavaScript, when you're accessing environment variables using import.meta.env, they are already provided as strings, so you don't need to explicitly convert them to strings using String(). This might be causing the "Type error: invalid URL" because the
